# A lot of Div need to go from green to white and white to red

Tags: jquery, html, colors

i have a page with a lot of divs created by database, each div appear with a different color, from green to red (i increase the red and decrease the green), but between, there is an ugly brown... so i think it's better to eyes to go from green to white, and white to green, but i can't find a solution  :/

```js
var R=0;
var V=255;
var B=0;
var divi=255/($('.ordreprio').length-1);
$('.ordreprio').each(function(){

  $(this).css("background-color","rgb("+R+","+V+","+B+")");
       
  R=R+divi;
  V=V-divi;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recherchemot">
 
    <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 8
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours8"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="8"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 4
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours4"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="4"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 5
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours5"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="5"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 6
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours6"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="6"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 1
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours1"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="1"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 2
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours2"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="2"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
            <div class="ordreprio">
        mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 3
            <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours3"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="3"></form>    </div>
        <br><br>
          
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use [HSL](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) units when I need to generate such gradients. Red has a hue of 0 (`hsl(0, 100%, 50%)`), and Green is 120 (`hsl(120, 100%, 50%)`), so by changing the hue from 0 to 120 you can change the color from red to green. (Instead of having white in between, you get yellow though.)

Here's your example updated with that:

```js
var red = 0;
var green = 120;
var increment = (red + green) / ($('.ordreprio').length - 1);

var hue = red;
$('.ordreprio').each(function() {

  $(this).css("background-color", "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%)");

  hue += increment;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recherchemot">

  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 8
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours8"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="8"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 4
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours4"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="4"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 5
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours5"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="5"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 6
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours6"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="6"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 1
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours1"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="1"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 2
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours2"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="2"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="ordreprio">
    mon texte par a été trouvé 1 fois sur le cours 3
    <form method="post" action="./coursrecherche.php" name="formcours3"><input type="hidden" name="valuecours" value="3"></form>
  </div>
  <br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: it's better than the brown :p thank you it helped me, i never try HSL before it's interresting :)